# Android Custom String Format

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, textview, decimalformat

I Have a `EditText` and `TextView` in my app and i want when in `EditText` enter number,this number display whit custom format,but Is not.

```
private int billAmount = 0;  
private TextView amountTextView;

amountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(amountEditTextWatcher);


private final TextWatcher amountEditTextWatcher=new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, 
                                           int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, 
                                           int i, int i1, int i2) {
            try {

                DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###");
                df.format(billAmount);
                amountTextView.setText(amountEditText.getText().toString());
                billAmount=Integer.parseInt(amountEditText.getText().toString());
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                amountTextView.setText("");
                billAmount=0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
        try {
                DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###");
                amountTextView.setText(df.format(Integer.parseInt(amountEditText.getText().toString())));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                amountTextView.setText("");
                billAmount=0;
            }
```